# Serial bluetooth to Roomba iRobot

Tags: c, bluetooth, vhdl, fpga, xilinx

So I may have done something VERY foolish

I've agreed to a project where a Roomba is controlled via bluetooth.  I thought everything was fine and dandy, BUT, I'm not allowed a computer for the end system.

Instead, I'm allowed a Xilinx Virtex II Pro board.

My plan is to buy a bluetooth serial adapter, and buy the iRobot accessory to foster the communication.  My hope is that it'll be about as hard as sending messages over a serial port (and I won't have to deal with too much low level socket programming, but if I have to I have to).

My question is, has anyone done something similar to this?  Can anyone recommend a tutorial, or a website or a specific product?

I'm aiming to buy these:
http://store.irobot.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2649971

http://overlandresource.com/wp-content/gallery/images/bluetooth-serialconverter.png

Can anyone recommend something better?  Can anyone tell me what trouble I'm in for?  Really, ANY advice would be nice.

To clarify this project has to be in C and VHDL as C.

Comment: Serial communications in VHDL is easy.  For more complicated protocols, you might want a soft-processor, I think a Virtex should be able to handle one just fine.

Comment: I've actually never tried it with VHDL, my plan was to do that in C, but heck, never hurts to learn a new trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pretty much just plug and play a Bluetooth module that will do Serial Port Profile e.g. it looks and works like a serial port, even down to RS-232 type connections to the module.

For example, I've played with an RN-42 module by RoHS and it works pretty well. I am pretty sure there are others out there as well.

However, you will have to somehow pair the two ends of the Bluetooth connection. Might involve one end knowing the fixed pin number of the other end. That's going to be down to the modules you end up using.

Don't expect high baud rates either.

Comment: Your confidence is reassuring!  I thought I was hosed, but this makes me feel a lot more confident about this project.  Thanks!

Comment: RN-42 is made by Roving Networks.  Great device.  (RoHS is the standard for manufacturing without lead)

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I am a SW engineer by trade and I burn myself with the soldering iron whenever I try any of that tricky HW stuff.

Answer (score 1):

So I hope my response isn't too late, but a great tutorial that covers EXACTLY what you are looking for is here:

http://www.robotappstore.com/Knowledge-Base/1-Introduction-to-Roomba-Programming/15.html

It goes over the setup, communication, and basic use of the roomba SCI commands.  What's great about the roomba is that you can use any sorta of lanugage you wish to actually handle all your complicated computing, and then just send down your motion commands to the roomba.

Controlling the roomba is pretty easy, just the setup is the most difficult part.  The other annoying thing is that the roomba's commands are not in plain ASCII chars, but rather sent in byte form.  Once you get over that, its a breeze though.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm afraid you are a bit late (by about 6 months), but I was able to get it all working fine.  I was able to use a serial to bluetooth adapter and use printf() to send commands.  Worked like a breeze.  But thanks for the effort.  Have an upvote!